# How to embed matplotlib plot PyQt5 QGroupBox

Tags: matplotlib, plot, pyqt5

I need to embed a plot into the PyQt widget. I can open the txt file with QFileDialog and plot the data separately, but I need to embed the figure into the initial solution group box. Here is the UI image.
[image: Main Window]

And here is my main code.

```
import sys
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QDialog, QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QAction
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MainScreen(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("ilk_deneme.ui", self)
        self.MenuBar()
        

    def MenuBar(self):
        Open_Data = self.actionOpen_Data
        Open_Data.triggered.connect(self.open_sheet)
        

    def open_sheet(self):
        path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open", "", "TXT Files (*.txt)")
        if path[0]!='':
            self.FileN=path[0]
        self.dta_list = pd.read_csv(self.FileN,sep=",",header=None,names=["1","2"])  
        df = self.dta_list
        ax = df.plot.scatter(x="1",y="2",c="black")
        for k, v in df.iterrows():
            ax.annotate(k, v)
        plt.show()


        


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
MainScreen = MainScreen()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(MainScreen)
widget.setFixedHeight(656)
widget.setFixedWidth(1097)
widget.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `FigureCanvas` from the axis figure, then add that to the layout.

The following assumes that the "Initial Solution" group box is called `initialSolution`. Since you didn't provide the UI, I don't know if that box already has a layout or not, so I check for it and eventually create one.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

# ...

    def open_sheet(self):
        # ...
        ax = df.plot.scatter(x="1",y="2",c="black")
        for k, v in df.iterrows():
            ax.annotate(k, v)

        layout = self.initialSolution.layout()
        if layout is None:
            layout = QVBoxLayout(self.initialSolution)

        canvas = FigureCanvas(ax.figure)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar(canvas, self)
        layout.addWidget(toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(canvas)
```

<sup>Note: you're probably basing your UI on a youtube tutorial that is known to provide a **lot** of terrible suggestions, like adding QMainWindow (or worse, QDialog) to a QStackedWidget or that `try/except` block that doesn't consider nor show the exception type; I strongly discourage you to follow anything from that tutorial, and look for other sources instead. Also, `MenuBar()` has a name that is dangerously similar to the QMainWindow [`menuBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#menuBar) function (and it also has a capitalized name, which is discouraged for functions); always use more descriptive names for variables and functions.</sup>

Comment: I used the FigureCanvas and it worked clean, thanks a lot. And also thanks for the note

Comment: can you please add more details about your implementation? I have been struggling for many hours to integrate, as clean as possible, a plt axis into a pyqt5 GUI but in vain.

Comment: @yuri the code above is just a rewriting of one function, the rest is exactly as the code in the question, so there are no further details to be added. I suggest to start from there and try to understand the concept behind it so that you can apply it to your case. If you still cannot figure it out, then create a new question and provide an appropriate [mre] of your attempt(s).